# function approximation - identifying suitable functions to evaluate

Tags: nonlinear-analysis, extrapolation

I want to approximate best fitting function using first 3 inputs of X,Y values and then extrapolates for X=[5,20]. X=[2,20] and Y=[0,100], in the attached plot. which kind of function is likely to fit best, rational, log, exp, any other....

Comment: Where is the attached plot??

Comment: Before we even see any plot, let me ask you: What are your own thoughts about the best fit function, when you look at the data that you have? You know how a linear function looks like, as well as logarithmic and exponential and polynomial ... Which one would **you** choose?

Comment: It seems I am not allowed to post an image, X=[2...20] and Y =  [ 0.202, 0.244, 0.54, 1.16, 1.886, 2.95, 4.194, 5.696, 7.758, 9.354, 11.118, 13.568, 15.422, 18.776, 21.678, 23.67, 26.834, 27.95, 31.81]. Matti. P. : I would like to restate my question: Given the input, which function type will provide best fitting function using only first 3 inputs.

Comment: Why is it important to only look at the first three points? Anyway, as a whole, when you plot all of the points, a not-bad approximation is
$$
f(x)  \approx 0.081 x^2 + 0.045 x - 0.882
$$
which is a polynomial trend plot. But this is for all of the 19 points.

Comment: ... but if you really need to only look at three points, the best and easiest fit (if you only want to look at the value of $R^2$) is a **polynomial of 2nd degree**. But can you see why this is a problem? It could be that the result from that is not a good approximation for the rest of the data.

Comment: Thanks Matti P. for your replies. I need to take measurements on a 4 core desktop and extrapolate for a 20 core server, hence first 3 inputs. phenomena I am measuring appears for no of cores>=2. I evaluated a lot of function types and a particular function  -  alog(bx)-c/x - works for most of the cases(R^2>95, inputs increased to 4 cores instead of 3), but not all.  Given the constraints, I would like to know whether I should evaluate different types of functions?